# Can't change size of background image

Tags: html, css

I can't get a background to fit the whole window

In a section of my website I am getting something like this:

[image: what i dont want]

where it should appear like in the intro page:

[image: what I want]

Bellow is the CSS and HTML code for the non-working one.

```css
.content-section {
  padding-top: 100px;
}
.download-section {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 50px 0;
  color: white;
  background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lpZc.jpg') no-repeat center center scroll;
  background-color: black;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
}
#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  margin-top: 100px;
}
@media (min-width: 767px) {
  .content-section {
    padding-top: 250px;
  }
  .download-section {
    padding: 100px 0;
  }
  #map {
    height: 400px;
    margin-top: 1000px;
  }
}
```

```html
<section id="comojogar" class="content-section text-center">
        <div class="download-section">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
                    <h2>Download Grayscale</h2>
      <!--<video width="720" height="480" controls="controls">
      <source src="video/1.mp4" type="video/mp4"> 
      <object data="" width="720" height="480"> 
      <embed width="720" height="480" src="video/1.mp4">
     </video>--> 
     
                    <p>You can download Grayscale for free on the preview page at Start Bootstrap.</p>
                    <a href="http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/grayscale/" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Visit Download Page</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: When I added a picture to your code your code is working. You have to check for class override or in line style for your element.

Comment: @PradeepSapkota So can you get it to work? I am new to CSS, could you explain better what is in line style of element?

Answer (score 2):

Try this :D

```
.download-section {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 50px 0;
  color: white;
  background: #000 url(../img/fundo1.jpg) no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover !important;
}
```

Comment: try put this in your css: `* {background-size: cover !important;}`
then tell me if that work or not

Comment: and also make sure your image file is really have no black color space in the top and bottom >w< (if that's the case, you should edit the picture)